# Python: NameError when trying to print a previously defined variable in an else statement of handling error delcaration

Tags: python, error-handling, variable-names

I have the following simple code that aims to redefine the variable `y` when it is mathematically impossible for it to be the divisor of `x`:

```
x = 5
y = 0

while True:
    try:
        z = x/y
    except:
        while True:
            try:
                print("error in the division. Please, redefine y")
                y = int(input("y = __"))
            except:
                print("Redefine y properly__")
                continue
            else:
                print("All done")
                print(z)
                break
```

When I am asked to introduce the input and I introduce an integer like `3` I get the following ouput and the error:

> > error in the division. Please, redefine y y = __3 All done
> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call
> > last)  in 
> > 5     try:
> > ----> 6         z = x/y
> > 7     except:
>
> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 15             else:
> 16                 print("All done")
> ---> 17                 print(z)
> 18                 break
> 19
>
> NameError: name 'z' is not defined

I expected:

1. Not having an error in the division, as the division `5/3` makes sense
2. Not getting the error which says that name `z` is not defined, as it is defined in the 3rd line of the code: `z = x/y`

Could anyone help me? This is for an assignment of a Python course, so I am a beginner on it.

Edit: Beyond the solution provided below, I found the one to my specific code:

```
x = 5
y = 0

while True:
    try:
        z = x/y
        break
    except:
        while True:
            print("error in the division. Please, redefine y")
            try:
                y = int(input("y = __"))
                break
            except:
                print("Redefine y properly__")
                continue

print("All done")
print(z)
```

Comment: After you redefine `y` you don't redo the division before `print(z)`

Comment: Hint: Lines above execute before lines below. The attempt to assign  `z` happens before the second loop, and fails. Generally speaking, avoid blanket `except` statements, as they will hide bugs and introduce new ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO your code is a bit over-complicated. My understanding is that you actually want the program to end once the user provides any non-zero input. Thus, you only need a single `while True`. Also, I don't quite understand why you force the code to throw `ZeroDivisionError` before even the user provides any input. You can omit the part where you initialise `y` to `0` and let the user provide a command-line argument from the very beginning.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
x = 5

while True:
    try:
        y = int(input("y = __"))
        z = x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("error in the division. Please, redefine y")
        continue
    else:
        print("All done")
        print(z)
        break
```

Comment: It is a simplifying solution, I am editing my answer though since I found the solution for my specific code. I have to declare y = 0 before initalizing the loop because it is a requirement for the assignment

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to print `z` before you repeat the outer loop, so you haven't performed the division with the corrected `y`. Take that out of the loop, it should be after the outer loop so that it waits for the division to succeed and for the user to enter a valid replacement.

And use `break` to break out of the main loop when the division is successful.

```
x = 5
y = 0

while True:
    try:
        z = x/y
        break
    except:
        while True:
            try:
                print("error in the division. Please, redefine y")
                y = int(input("y = __"))
            except:
                print("Redefine y properly__")
                continue

print("All done")
print(z)
break
```

Comment: If I have to take out the last three lines from the outer loop, is it necessary that I declare the `break` at the end?

Comment: Yes, I just added that.

Comment: Upvoted becuase it helpled but was not the solution, I have posted it in my last edit